# Django login user=username never true

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I am having problems with my Django login.

The below if statement (if user is not None:) always resolves as false, so it moves onto the else.

I'm not sure why and I would appreciate any help

Thanks

VIEWS.PY

```
def index(request):
    return render(request, 'home.html', {})

def login_user(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user = request.POST.get('username')
        password = request.POST.get('password')
        user = authenticate(username=user, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            messages.success(request, ('You are logged in'))
            return redirect('index')
        else:
            messages.success(request, ('Login failed'))
            return redirect('login')
    else:    
        return render(request, 'login.html', {})
```

And here is the login form:

```
    <form name="form1", id="form1" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
      <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="user" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter email">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Password"> 
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Login</button>
  </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to give your `<input>` elements a `name` attribute, so that you can identify them in your Python code.

```
<input name="username" type="text" class="form-control" id="user" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter email">
...
<input name="password" type="password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Password">
```

The `name` has to match `request.POST.get(<this>)`.

Comment: you are awesome!